# Check PasswordBox if user type anything in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, passwords, passwordbox

I am using `PasswordBox` and I want to detect whenever the user typed there anything, if yes I need to change Button status to enabled. How can I check if user types anything
in the `PasswordBox`?

It behaves differently from `TextBox` since you can't bind it to text
and when user types anything raises some event. Any idea?

I have tried with the code below, but I get errors:

```
<PasswordBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <si:InvokeDataCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>  
</PasswordBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`PasswordChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.passwordchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event via `Interactions` like this:

**`XAML`**

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<PasswordBox BorderBrush="#FFB0B1AB"
             Width="100"
             Height="25"
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChangedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</PasswordBox>
```

**`RelayCommand`**

```
private ICommand _passwordChangedCommand = null;

public ICommand PasswordChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_passwordChangedCommand == null)
        {
            _passwordChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.PasswordChanged(), null);
        }

        return _passwordChangedCommand;
    }
}

private void PasswordChanged()
{
    // your logic here
}
```

**`Some useful links`**

[`PasswordBox in WPF Tutorial`](http://wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html)

[`Binding to PasswordBox in WPF (using MVVM)`](http://seesharpdeveloper.blogspot.ru/2013/03/binding-to-passwordbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm.html)

[How to bind to a PasswordBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `PasswordChanged` event which fires when the string in the passwordbox changes:

XAML Part:

```
<PasswordBox Name="pwdBox" PasswordChanged="pwdBox_PasswordChanged" />
<Button Name="someButton" IsEnabled="False" Click="someClickEvent" />
```

C# Part:

```
    private void pwdBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        somebutton.IsEnabled = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pwdBox.Password));
    }
```

Please note that MSDN says

> When you get the Password property value, you expose the password as plain text in memory. To avoid this potential security risk, use the SecurePassword property to get the password as a SecureString.

Therefore the following code may be preferred:

```
    private void pwdBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn.IsEnabled = pwdBox.SecurePassword.Length == 0;
    }
```

If you only have access to viewModel, then you may use attached properties such that you create a bindable password or securepassword, as [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888466/passwordbox-binding)

Comment: Thanks mcy +1, the problem is that I dont have in view cs the instance of the model view,there is a way to call to this event in the model view itself?you can see that I try with the updated question

Comment: This is good answer. It is way simpler than the accepted answer. Also, if the button is enabled by default, you can add, in the code behind constructor, call:   pwdBox_PasswordChanged("", new RoutedEventArgs()) and assuming the pwdBox is blank (should be), it will set it to Not Enabled when the page opens.