# WPF key bindings all keys in passwordbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have this passwordbox :

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="textBox1">
   <PasswordBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
   </PasswordBox.InputBindings>
</PasswordBox>
```

I want to bind my command with all keys, and not just enter.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes possible.  Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22128838/2819451)

Comment: Can I put the logic in my viewmodel with this solution?